# Adding product variant title in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I've got a few products that have different variants - i.e. Colour, Size, etc.

I'm trying to output the parent(?) variant title using - {{ variant.title }} but that's only outputting the variant options themselves  i.e. Small, Medium, Large for Size.  Is there a way to output the "Size" title and not the individual variant titles.

Sorry if that's confusing, I know I'm in the close but maybe in the wrong ball park!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the option titles are available on the `variant` object - for those you would normally look on the parent `product` object.

If you are printing the variant details from the context of a product page (or other situation where you already have a `product` object), you can use [product.options](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product#product-options) or [product.options_with_values](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product#product-options_with_values) to get the option category names.  The option names will always be in the same order as the option values are listed on the variant, so the first value of the `product.options` array will be for the first item in the `variant.options` array.

Once an item is added to the cart, the resulting `line_item` object gets its own style of an [options_with_values](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/line_item#line_item-options_with_values) object that has the names and values of the associated options, but unfortunately this object does not appear to exist on the `variant` object itself.

*Above links all go to the relevant Shopify Liquid reference pages*

Answer (score 0):

Using {{ product.options }} worked for this. I was able to output Size/Flavor for different products and their variant option titles.